# Add a corpus to the NLTK corpus, and importing it

Tags: python, import, nltk, corpus

I have created a corpus consisting of a collection of .txt files, and would like to start using the NLTK (python) on them.

I have navigated to the /nltk_data/corpora/ where NLTK comes with some pre-defined corpora (gutenberg, shakespear, etc.) to be tested by the platform.

However, when I attempted to add my own file (containing the several .txt files), and import it using

`from nltk.corpus import [name of my file]`

I receive this message back:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import [name of my file]
ImportError: cannot import name '[name of my file]'`

What am I doing wrong? Also, what's the method of calling in my file from any other place?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't add new corpora in `nltk_data`. See the code in the linked question's text for how to set up your own corpus.

Comment: @alexis Thanks for the link, once I've done this do you have any pointers on how I can use the NLTK functions with my new corpus? It's not as easy or straightforward as with the built-in corpora.

Comment: Look at the snippet in the question. Once you've created a `PlaintextCorpusReader` object, you can use the methods `fileids()`, `sents()`, and `words()` just like with the built-in objects.

Comment: @alexis Yeah got it working, thanks for your help!

Comment: Create PlaintextCorpusReader and pass the corpus_root to it.
Src: Section 1.9 in http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html